What's the difference between 伤心 and 难过？
What's the difference between 伤心 and 难过？
I know that both mean "sad", but is there any subtle difference?
Thanks!

丢了女朋友叫伤心。丢了钱包叫难过。

I lost my walet, I have no any money now, 日子很難過. I lost my girlses, I have no any girl friend now, 感覺很傷心 .

Both "伤心" (shāngxīn) and "难过" (nánguò) describe feelings of sadness, but they have slightly different connotations and usages in Chinese.

伤心 (shāngxīn):

Literally translates to "heartbroken" or "hurt at heart."
Usually implies a deeper, more intense level of emotional pain.
Often associated with significant or personal events, such as the loss of a loved one, a breakup, or a betrayal.
Example: 她因为失去了亲人而伤心了好久。 (She was heartbroken for a long time because she lost a loved one.)


难过 (nánguò):

Literally translates to "feeling bad" or "having a hard time."
Can describe a range of negative emotions, from mild sadness to significant distress.
Often used in a broader context, not necessarily tied to deeply personal events.
Example: 他听到坏消息时感到很难过。 (He felt very sad when he heard the bad news.)



In summary, "伤心" tends to describe a more profound and personal sadness, while "难过" is a more general term for feeling sad or distressed.

Well explained.

伤心 and 难过 can both mean sad.
However 伤心 is basically limited to sad(or heartbroken), the mental state, specifically, while 难过 can also stand for physical uncomfort.

The degree is different
伤心(injurying heart) = sad; sorrow; heartbroken
难过(hard to bear) = uncomfortable; unhappy; sad
You can't use 伤心 for uncomfortable or unhappy (too mild)
You can't use 难过 for sorrow or heartbroken (too severe)
Also, 难过 can be physical, but not 伤心 which is all mental. For example, if you have difficulty breathing, you can say you feel 难过 (uncomfortable) but not 伤心
